# The object 'XXXX' is dependent on column 'XXXX'

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Quando tento alterar o tipo da chave primária de uma tabela, obtenho o seguinte erro:

> ```
> The object 'XXXX' is dependent on column 'XXXX'.
> ```

Gostaria de saber qual a forma "menos" manual de resolver esse erro sem ter que desabilitar as dependências uma por uma.